# Algorithm wanted: placing harbours in a hex-tile map to ensure intercontinental travel

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I am making a game that uses hexagonal tiles to represent a map; the tiles, or hexes, each contains pointers to all its neighbours in list form. The map may look like the following:

[image]

The large green region are the "Mainland" whereas the small yellow region is the "Island", the rest are generic water bodies, note that small pockets of water maybe trapped inside the mainland.

The mainland and the island are always contiguous and never boarder one another. The player will occupy a single hex at any one time. Basic movement moves the player from one hex to another provided the origin and destination are adjacent, and that the movement does not move the player from a land hex to a water hex.

"Harbours" are an upcoming feature which are placed in hexes of the mainland or island, they allow the player to move from the harbour to any adjacent water-hex, this should enable travel between the land bodies

**Problem:**
I want to place at least 2 harbours in a map like this to ensure that the player can always go from the mainland to the island and vice versa.

This is harder than it seems because of the following complications:

1. Harbours will be useless if they are placed on the shore of a land-locked water body
2. The mainland may divide the sea into multiple parts, so that the harbours may not be placed on the right shore to be useful (in the example below; H1 and H2 cannot communicate exclusively through the water while H2 and H3 can)

[image: figure 2]

As such, I'd welcome any clear description of a suitable algorithm for placing harbours on maps like these, and any pseudocode will be highly appreciated

Comment: [Is your question answered?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Plain BFS or Bidirectional BFS.

Start a BFS from hexes touching water - orange cells. If the BFSs meet in the middle, place a harbor on those land regions. This will help avoid cases like harbor H1 because the BFS from cells like H1 won't meet any other land region.

[image]

Note: In your post you are not looking for minumum harbors to be placed. Again, BFS will be helpful there, though, it would need more handling in implementation. See the map below. Red ones are minimum harbors placed on the map.

[image]